# Terraform behind the password protected proxy command

Tags: proxy, terraform

I have set the proxy in command as following

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://user:passowrd@host.com:8080
set HTTPS_PROXY=https://user:passowrd@host.com:8080
set HTTP_USER=myuser
set HTTP_PASSWORD=mypwd
```

and future more I have set environment variable as HTTP_PROXY, HTTPS_PROXY, HTTP_USER, HTTP_PASSWORD
Somehow still getting following error

```
>terraform init
Initializing the backend...
Initializing provider plugins...
- Checking for available provider plugins...
Registry service unreachable.
This may indicate a network issue, or an issue with the requested Terraform Registry.
Error: registry service is unreachable, check https://status.hashicorp.com/ for status updates
```

please note that https://status.hashicorp.com/ having access behind the proxy. 
but I am not sure `terraform init` actually which URL/service API is getting access

Answer (score -1):

Working for me with proxy:
C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\VMWare_Scripts\Terraform>set HTTP_PROXY=http://xxxx:8080

C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\VMWare_Scripts\Terraform>terraform init

Initializing the backend...

Initializing provider plugins...

- Finding latest version of hashicorp/vsphere...
- Installing hashicorp/vsphere v1.24.1...
- Installed hashicorp/vsphere v1.24.1 (signed by HashiCorp)

The following providers do not have any version constraints in configuration,
so the latest version was installed.

To prevent automatic upgrades to new major versions that may contain breaking
changes, we recommend adding version constraints in a required_providers block
in your configuration, with the constraint strings suggested below.

- hashicorp/vsphere: version = "~> 1.24.1"

Terraform has been successfully initialized!

You may now begin working with Terraform. Try running "terraform plan" to see
any changes that are required for your infrastructure. All Terraform commands
should now work.

If you ever set or change modules or backend configuration for Terraform,
rerun this command to reinitialize your working directory. If you forget, other
commands will detect it and remind you to do so if necessary.